# Difference between "No" and "Cancel" in MessageBoxButtons

Tags: c#, messagebox

I was using a MessageBox to show a confirmation message when the user goes to delete an item and initially used MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel. Later I changed it to YesNo instead because a user pointed out that there was no real difference in "No" and "Cancel" in this case. My question is...what is the difference? Is there ever a reason to use YesNoCancel instead of YesNo?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com might be more appropriate.

Comment: From the [c#] tag I assume that you are targetting the Windows operating system. Microsoft has some detailed guidance about dialog boxes including message boxes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511268.aspx. Highly recommended reading if you are designing a user interface for Windows.

Comment: I have edited my response below. Please see my change. Handling cancel is important, even in YesNo dialog boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there could be.  For example, if there is a save dialog and you enter a filename that already exists, the dialog could ask you if you want to overwrite the file.

Yes would mean overwrite the file. No might mean append a "(1)" at the end of the file name, or prompt for a different file name.  Cancel might mean don't save after-all.

You should note that `Yes`, `No`, and `Cancel` are all different enums and do not have the same value, so you can treat them differently.

REMEMBER TO HANDLE CANCEL ANYWAY because if the user clicks the `x` button in the top right corner of your dialog screen, the result of `ShowDialog()` is `DialogResult.Cancel`!

Answer (score 7):

In your case there is no difference as your question results in just one action and then finishes.

In standard usage, the Yes No Cancel usually asks a question, Yes or No will chose a different action and then proceed to do yet another action (like quitting a form), Cancel will abandon all actions.

For example: quitting Word, do you wish to save?  "Yes, No, Cancel".  Yes and No will continue to quit with or without saving, cancel will not save or quit.

Whatever you do, make sure Cancel does what the user expects most - I forever spam cancel if bombarded with message boxes when I have got to focus on something else.  If I cancel something I don't want to lose a lot of work because I didn't have time to stop and handle it properly.

Users abuse cancel :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of when YesNoCancel would be appropriate:

"Would you like to save your changes before quitting?"

- Yes - Save and quit
- No - Don't save and quit
- Cancel - I pressed the button on accident, don't quit.

Answer (score 2):

Im sure its easy enough to come up with a scenario where there would be a symantic difference between "No" as a response and "Cancel". Traditionally "Cancel" should return the program to its state before starting the current series of operations. "No" certainly doesnt have this same rule.

Example:

> "Do you wish to delete file 4 of 10?"
>   Yes: Delete the file
>   No: Dont delete the file, move on to file 5 of 10
>   Cancel: Exit this operation and return to having not deleted any files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

Say you are exiting an application with an unsaved file, like a word processor.

There is a confirmation when exiting that says: "Your file has changes that haven't been saved. Would you like to save them?"

In this case:

Yes = save the file and exit

No = exit and lose the changes

Cancel = abort the exit and go back to the application

Answer (score 1):

I guess "Cancel" is used to abort the whole operation. If you are dealing with a huge procedure, for example, moving a set of files from one directory to another, you may want to ask something to the user about a specific file - for instance, to confirm if the user really wants to move a protected file. If the user presses "No", you ignore that item and continue the action. If the user presses "Cancel", you abort the whole action (and, maybe, rollback the previous action).

Of course, for a small procedure or a simple situation, "Cancel" and "No" have no difference.